# How to use omnifaces socket without CDI?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, omnifaces, java-websocket, primefaces-push

I would like to use Omnifaces Socket as an alternative solution for Primefaces Push which is on the way to remove in the future.
 I already checked the showcase(http://showcase.omnifaces.org/push/socket) and found that it needs the CDI to init the PushContext. unfortunately, **the framework**, we are working on, **CAN NOT support CDI**, so:
i**s there any chance that we can use the Omnifaces Socket without using CDI**?
If not can you suggest me **another solution to implement Websocket instead of PrimefacesPush**?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: As Socket is available since omnifaces 2.3 and omnifaces 2.x requires CDI, I don't think there will be a clean solution for using socket without CDI. What's your runtime environment? Maybe the servlet container already provides websocket capabilities?

Comment: the framework use Tomcat @Selaron I'm on the way to try [IcePush](http://www.icesoft.org/java/projects/ICEpush/overview.jsf) hope it work :D 
Thank you