# Using OmniFaces in Spring Boot project

Tags: spring-boot, jsf, omnifaces

I am using JSF with PrimeFaces in Spring Boot project.
Spring Boot version 2.7.8
JSF api and impl version: 2.2.20
PrimeFaces version: 12
It all works.

I want to use `o:socket` of OmniFaces. Basically I added just `omnifaces` dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>12.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.22</version>
    </dependency>
```

I got below error

```
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactory' was not configured properly.
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:330)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:236)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:439)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4762)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5222)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:430)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104)
    at com.infina.myapplication.myapplicationApplication$1.getTomcatWebServer(myapplicationApplication.java:31)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:184)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
    at com.infina.myapplication.myapplicationApplication.main(myapplicationApplication.java:21)
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactoryImpl
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinderInstance.java:407)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinderInstance.java:251)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:543)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:283)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:328)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.omnifaces.util.BeansLocal.resolve(BeansLocal.java:69)
    at org.omnifaces.util.BeansLocal.getReference(BeansLocal.java:84)
    at org.omnifaces.util.Beans.getReference(Beans.java:132)
    at org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplication.<init>(OmniApplication.java:67)
    at org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplicationFactory.createOmniApplication(OmniApplicationFactory.java:86)
    at org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplicationFactory.getApplication(OmniApplicationFactory.java:51)
    at com.sun.faces.application.InjectionApplicationFactory.getApplication(InjectionApplicationFactory.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:142)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactoryImpl.<init>(ClientWindowFactoryImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinderInstance.java:405)
    ... 45 more
2023-05-03/08:48:40.857 logging.DirectJDKLog           ERROR Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactory' was not configured properly.
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4762)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5222)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:430)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104)
    at com.infina.myapplication.myapplicationApplication$1.getTomcatWebServer(myapplicationApplication.java:31)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:184)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
    at com.infina.myapplication.myapplicationApplication.main(myapplicationApplication.java:21)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactory' was not configured properly.
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:330)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:236)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:439)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:227)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactoryImpl
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinderInstance.java:407)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinderInstance.java:251)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:543)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:283)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:328)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.omnifaces.util.BeansLocal.resolve(BeansLocal.java:69)
    at org.omnifaces.util.BeansLocal.getReference(BeansLocal.java:84)
    at org.omnifaces.util.Beans.getReference(Beans.java:132)
    at org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplication.<init>(OmniApplication.java:67)
    at org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplicationFactory.createOmniApplication(OmniApplicationFactory.java:86)
    at org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplicationFactory.getApplication(OmniApplicationFactory.java:51)
    at com.sun.faces.application.InjectionApplicationFactory.getApplication(InjectionApplicationFactory.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:142)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactoryImpl.<init>(ClientWindowFactoryImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinderInstance.java:405)
    ... 45 more
2023-05-03/08:48:40.858 logging.DirectJDKLog           ERROR One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2023-05-03/08:48:40.859 logging.DirectJDKLog           ERROR Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2023-05-03/08:48:40.861 faces.FactoryFinderInstance    ERROR Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. Attempting to find backup.
2023-05-03/08:48:40.862 config.ConfigureListener       ERROR Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. 
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:555)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:283)
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:140)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4810)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5463)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:187)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:430)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104)
    at com.infina.myapplication.myapplicationApplication$1.getTomcatWebServer(myapplicationApplication.java:31)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:184)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
    at com.infina.myapplication.myapplicationApplication.main(myapplicationApplication.java:21)
2023-05-03/08:48:41.080 boot.SpringApplication         ERROR Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
    at com.infina.myapplication.myapplicationApplication.main(myapplicationApplication.java:21)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104)
    at com.infina.myapplication.myapplicationApplication$1.getTomcatWebServer(myapplicationApplication.java:31)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:184)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.rethrowDeferredStartupExceptions(TomcatWebServer.java:187)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: @BalusC Sorry, I have looked through all messages about Primefaces and Omnifaces. I see somewhere you are supporting OmniFaces "socket" tag. So  I tried to use Primefaces and Omnifaces together. Also I see your other messages about "polluted runtime" I don't see any pollution. What doest it mean "CDI not available" ? What should I do to make it available ? If it is impossible why did you suggest using OmniFaces socket to someone using PrimeFaces ? I searched through JoinFaces but it doesn't exist in PrimeFaces 12 version which I am currently using. Thank you for you answers.

Comment: Now I see this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52961144/how-to-use-omnifaces-socket-without-cdi

Comment: I put all server console logs as requested also tried to implement your method to install CDI. https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2013/10/how-to-install-cdi-in-tomcat.html

Comment: @BalusC I updated error log and added pom.xml dependencies.

Comment: Error suggests that CDI is unavailable. CDI is one of the minimum requirements of OmniFaces 2.x according to https://omnifaces.org/#minimum-requirements The `o:socket` relies fully on CDI as well.

Comment: Joinfaces can help. It integrates jsf with spring boot. http://joinfaces.org/